# pygame Splitting sprite sheet then displaying each one not displaying all sprites

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, blit

I am working on grabbing a sprite sheet and just automating cutting each sprite out and I was wanting to just display each on on my screen to make sure I am grabbing them properly but it will only display 4 sprites and no more. Am I messing up the blit somewhere because there are 8 images in the list. Please note I have verified I am grabbing all of the proper images I was just wondering what I am doing wrong for them to not all display. I assume it is something to do with my x and y maybe.

Get all sprite class:

```
def getAllSprite(self,width,height):
    imWidth = self.spriteFile.get_width()
    imHeight = self.spriteFile.get_height()
    print(imWidth)
    finals = []
    x,y = 0,0

    for r in range(int(imWidth/width)):
        for c in range(int(imHeight/height)):
            print("Row: " + str(r) + " Column: " + str(c))
            print(x,y)
            finals.append(self.getSprite(x,y,width,height))
            print(c)
            
            y += height

            if y >= height:
                y = 0
                x += width
    return finals
```

display sprite function:

```
spriteSheet = SpriteSheet(basePath+"Sprites\\mmButtons.png")
sprites = spriteSheet.getAllSprite(282,69)
x,y = 0,0
for item in sprites:
    width, height = item.get_size()
    tv.blit(item, (x,y))

    x += width

    if x+width >= resW:
        x = 0
        y += height
```

Print output of sprites:

```
[<Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>, <Surface(282x69x32 SW)>]
```

input image:
[image]
output result:
[image]

Comment: without trying it myself I can't find a mistake just by looking at your code, looks good to me. I don't know how much it is, but you could add the necessary parts and I'll have a look. One more thing: did you try to print x and y directly after blitting the images? 1) do these values makes sense? 2) are there 8 print statements? you could also try to just change the code with static block size and blit them 8 images in 2 rows 4 columns (without getting width and height, just choose adequate numbers)

Comment: yes I have printed x and y and they make sense and the list has the surface in it but as you can see in the image its not I guess I am using the sprite sheet class in the docs to grab the sprite and I must use the image height to make it dynamic and be able to split almost any sprite sheet.

Comment: Where is the `SpriteSheet` class?

Comment: Do not apply the suggestions from an answer to the question, that makes the answer useless.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh I will re edit I am sorry I copied the section from  a test script I made with your answer my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if y >= height:` is always `True`, because you do `y += height` right before. Also you accidentally swapped `r` and `c`. Likely `r` is the row (y-axis) and `c` the column (x-axis).
I recommend simplifying your code. Simplify the loop to generate the sprites:

```py
def getAllSprite(self, width, height):
    imWidth = self.spriteFile.get_width()
    imHeight = self.spriteFile.get_height()
    print(imWidth)
    finals = []
    for c in range(imWidth // width):
        for r in range(imHeight // height):
            x = c * width
            y = r * height
            finals.append(self.getSprite(x, y, width, height))

    return finals
```

or

```py
def getAllSprite(self, width, height):
    imWidth = self.spriteFile.get_width()
    imHeight = self.spriteFile.get_height()
    print(imWidth)
    finals = []
    for x in range(0, imWidth, width):
        for y in range(0, imHeight, height):
            finals.append(self.getSprite(x, y, width, height))

    return finals
```

Comment: When I ran your code it cause nothing to show I was looking and using x and y in the for loop was telling the function to get them at that position so it was grabbing that same image in this example. I updated the question to include the get sprite function as well I am not sure what I am doing wrong it is either with grabbing the image its self or the position from my loop like I originally was thinking. Also is this question a better example of minimal functional code than in my previous question that you said that about?

Comment: I was able to solve the solution please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue it seems I was positions them over each other in the display function I was using with bad math (my bad). so i just passed their original position with them and it worked. This would not be needed if you are just wanting to store them and make your own positions. luckily I just wanted to make sure it was getting the images.

```
class SpriteSheet:
def __init__(self,spriteFile):
    self.spriteFile = pygame.image.load(spriteFile).convert_alpha()

def getAllSprite(self, width, height):
    imWidth = self.spriteFile.get_width()
    imHeight = self.spriteFile.get_height()
    finals = []
    x,y = 0,0

    for c in range(0, int(imHeight/height)):
        for r in range(0, int(imWidth/width)):
            finals.append([self.getSprite(x,y,width,height),x,y])

            if x >= width:
                x = 0
                y += height
            else:
                x += width

    return finals

for item in sprites:
    tv.blit(item[0], (item[1], item[2]))
```